# What does "by conditioning our tax return preparation services" mean?

Tags: tax-law

Referencing [Internal Revenue Bulletin 2013-3 (January 14, 2013)](https://www.irs.gov/irb/2013-03_IRB/ar09.html) 5(1)(a) specifically, there's some pretty confusing language here that I can't figure out what it means.

> If we obtain your signature on this form by conditioning our tax
>   return preparation services on your consent, your consent will not be
>   valid.

I encountered this while doing my free H&R tax return, and didn't want to agree to it without understanding what it's asking. From the context I assume it means that they're asking for consent to disclose information about my tax return, but that's really not clear.

Comment: Is the language from the IRS bulletin or H&R? Is there a larger context; consent of what? Are you able to provide a link to the full document that contains this paragraph?

Comment: @DaveD Sorry, I thought `Internal Revenue Bulletin 2013-3` was a unique identifier. Document is now linked in the question

Answer (score 4):

Reworded:

> If the only reason you provide consent is because otherwise we won't prepare your taxes then you really haven't provided consent at all.

Answer (score 3):

In context, this is an official notification that a tax preparer [`we`] must give to the tax preparee [`you`], if the tax preparer wishes to disclose the preparee's information to any other party.

Note that `we` in this context is the tax preparer, and `you` is the person reading the consent agreement.

> If `we` obtain ...[`your consent`]...
>
> by ...[refusing to provide service if `you` do not provide `your consent`]...
>
> [then] `your consent` will not be valid.

because `your consent` must not occur under duress.

Answer (score -2):

I *think* it means that if *you* add any conditions to their form it will not be valid.